# Reading value of characteristic after connecting to service Bluetooth Low Energy Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

after the connection is established I want to read the value from the characteristic and save the value in a byte array.

Here is my function for the reading inside my BluetoothLeService:

```
  public byte[] readWhiteAndIntensityCharacteristic() {
if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
    Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
    return null;
}
/*check if the service is available on the device*/
BluetoothGattService mCustomService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString(UuidAdresssService));
if (mCustomService == null) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Custom BLE Service not found");
    return null;
}
/*get the read characteristic from the service*/
BluetoothGattCharacteristic mReadCharacteristic = mCustomService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString(UuidAdresssWhiteAndIntensityCharastic));
byte[] messageByte = mReadCharacteristic.getValue();
if (messageByte != null && messageByte.length > 0) {
    final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(messageByte.length);
    for (byte byteChar : messageByte)
        stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X", byteChar));
    s = "0x" + stringBuilder.toString();
    Log.v("Scan Activity", s);
    if (mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(mReadCharacteristic) == false) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read characteristic");
    }
}
return messageByte;
```

}
This function get called inside my DeviceControlActivity:

```
    public void getStartUpValue(){
    Log.w(TAG, "Reading completed");}
  if(mBluetoothLeService.readWhiteAndIntensityCharacteristic() == null)
  {
      Log.w(TAG, "FAILED Reading value failed");
  }
    startValue = mBluetoothLeService.readWhiteAndIntensityCharacteristic();
    Log.w(TAG, "Reading completed");

}
```

I call the getStartUpValue function after the connection is established.

```
  private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
        mConnected = true;
        updateConnectionState(R.string.connected);
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
        mConnected = false;
        updateConnectionState(R.string.disconnected);
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        clearUI();
    } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
        // Show all the supported services and characteristics on the user interface.
        mBluetoothLeService.getSupportedGattServices();
        getStartUpValue();

    } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {
        displayData(intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA));

    }
}
```

};

The reading is failing everytime but sending values to the characteristic is no problem.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: what if you try `mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(mReadCharacteristic)`
instead of `mReadCharacteristic.getValue()`?

The result of the read operation is reported by the `onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic, int)` callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is: mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(mReadCharacteristic)

After the reading is finished a callback will be called.

Thanks to Andrew Vovk